# How do I have mapply apply the function to each row of each data frame in a list?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply, mapply

I am trying to calculate the angle between two vectors where both are in the same data frame, but each data frame is in a list. Here is what I tried with a MRE.

```
rm(list=ls())

coords <- rnorm(10)
x.h <- rnorm(10)
y.h <- rnorm(10)
liklihood.h <- rnorm(10)
x.MB <- rnorm(10)
y.MB <- rnorm(10)
x.a <- rnorm(10)
y.a <- rnorm(10)

day1 <-  data.frame(coords,x.h,y.h,liklihood.h,x.MB,y.MB,x.a,y.a)

coords <- rnorm(10)
x.h <- rnorm(10)
y.h <- rnorm(10)
liklihoo.d.h <- rnorm(10)
x.MB <- rnorm(10)
y.MB <- rnorm(10)
x.a <- rnorm(10)
y.a <- rnorm(10)

day2 <-  data.frame(coords,x.h,y.h,liklihood.h,x.MB,y.MB,x.a,y.a)

data <- list(day1,day2)

angle <- function(x,y){
  dot.prod <- x%*%y
  norm.x <- norm(x,type="2")
  norm.y <- norm(y,type="2")
  theta <- acos(dot.prod / (norm.x * norm.y))
  as.numeric(theta)

}

append_angles <- function(df1){ 
  vect1 = c((df1$x.h-df1$x.MB),(df1$y.h-df1$y.MB))
  vect2 = c((df1$x.a-df1$x.MB),(df1$y.a-df1$y.MB))
  df1$theta = (angle(vect1, vect2)*(180/pi)) 
  return(df1)
}

data <-  mapply(append_angles, data, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I end up getting the first value from the calculation repeated for each data frame instead of a calculation for each row. How do I make it so it calculates the value for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the function created, we can `split` by row and then apply

```
out <- Map(function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, seq_len(nrow(x))),
         append_angles)), data)
out
#[[1]]
#         coords        x.h         y.h liklihood.h        x.MB       y.MB        x.a         y.a      theta
#1  -0.545880758 -1.3169081 -0.07430856 -0.03373792  0.06735770  0.5266526  1.4520752  0.14379993 141.077262
#2   0.536585304  0.5982691 -0.60515695 -0.58542756  0.01710596 -1.0736261  0.4082015 -0.88610999  13.255879
#3   0.419623149 -0.7622144 -1.70964518  0.61285136 -0.34365937  0.7696819 -0.4403340 -0.02557419   2.651103
#4  -0.583627199 -1.4290903 -0.26869311  1.51712249 -0.66789220  1.7709054  1.3185662 -0.32773539  63.893042
#5   0.847460017  0.3322444 -0.64859151  0.65738044 -0.25574457 -0.1961822  0.5713866 -0.07596102  45.845198
#6   0.266021979 -0.4690607 -0.09411013 -1.07418134 -0.46120796  0.2047497 -1.2799872 -1.35466363  26.196849
#7   0.444585270 -0.3349868 -0.08554095 -4.46956441  1.47164158 -0.5965981 -1.2388796 -0.96080882  23.448044
#8  -0.466495124  1.5362522  0.11953107  0.36904502 -0.09196032  1.1782477 -0.9225911  0.22495434  98.033303
#9  -0.848370044  0.6099945 -0.11629639  0.16922669  0.33519430  1.0494212  1.3496121 -0.12316046  27.599124
#10  0.002311942  0.5163357 -0.94382724 -1.82219032 -0.23186459  0.5609812 -1.5676166  0.00104102  93.693684

#[[2]]
#         coords        x.h         y.h liklihood.h        x.MB        y.MB          x.a         y.a      theta
#1  -0.571243248 -0.2327672  0.08314367 -0.03373792  1.01283626 -2.46745604  0.667163872 -0.07045269  17.822834
#2   0.422621775 -1.4203631  2.78494703 -0.58542756  0.02534344 -0.05040743 -0.008576239 -0.75031916 150.209075
#3  -1.673385810 -0.8133227  0.59528232  0.61285136 -0.50715002  0.24643818  0.092440453 -0.09401376 160.860935
#4  -1.136025931  0.4610693  0.07766635  1.51712249 -0.50694324  1.53136287  0.320282642  0.41274946   2.823761
#5   0.361212489 -0.2148936 -0.55869661  0.65738044  0.26498877  0.59163787  0.165091251 -1.25747896  19.551954
#6   1.056864213  0.1389452 -0.80676768 -1.07418134  0.59168174 -1.61854195 -1.053206734  0.19706349  13.026765
#7  -1.992920453  0.8442304 -0.51070906 -4.46956441 -0.28834071 -0.63493218  0.447394677 -1.89231492  65.926033
#8   0.764385054 -1.3084503 -0.55648712  0.36904502 -0.52907038  1.35675449  1.057136825  0.25217616  77.312082
#9   0.007165349  1.0451687  0.24112516  0.16922669 -0.17986538 -0.75802712 -1.475157330 -0.64785092 135.937090
#10  0.101974336  1.2101739 -0.57533702 -1.82219032 -0.93043770  0.37536404  0.200732860 -0.26605768   5.607831
```

Comment: This worked, but my actual data includes very large lists of large data frames so this method takes a VERY long time... is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @K8Otter in that case, your initial function needs  to be changed because it is creating a constraint with `$`  i.e. asssuming that the dataset is data.frame